# Create a class from a new name

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I am relatively new to Intellij IDEA (now on 13.1.3, community edition) and so far I like it a lot and think it has the best parts of Eclipse and NetBeans without their defects. Nevertheless, I am puzzled about not finding a feature *(when coding in Scala)* which I use a lot, especially when TDD-ing: create/generate a class (or trait) from a new name. I suppose this should be an intention action, but Alt + Enter doesn't offer this option. *It works for Java, but not for Scala.*

I looked for an advice on the net but couldn't find anything useful.

Is there a shortcut to generate a class/interface from a new name when working with Scala?

Thank you in advance for your help.

**UPDATE**

[Issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-7247) added to Scala Plugin issues page. Though later found out I duplicated [this 3 years old issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-3400) :/

Answer (score 0):

Alt + Enter should do the trick - just type the name of the class in the code, you put the cursour on the class name and press ALT + Enter.

Doing this, here's what I get in IntelliJ 13.0.2 (though it's done this in every version I can remember):

[image: Screen shot of IntelliJ's Create Class feature]

Once you click `Create Class 'Example'`, you'll be prompted for the package then IntelliJ will do the rest.

**UPDATE**

Yes, unfortunately, it appears that with Scala the class creation feature doesn't exist:

[image]

Probably worth checking if it's on the issues list (accessible via the [Scala Plugin's home page](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/SCA/Scala+Plugin+for+IntelliJ+IDEA)) and if not, it's worth adding - it looks like JetBrains are pretty active in the development of the Scala plugin.

Comment: What I didn't mention is that I am trying to get it in Scala. Sorry, my fault, will update the question.

Comment: I opened an issue, adding your images from here. Hope you don't mind. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you've changed your default keymap (say, to match Eclipse's), <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> should provide you a list of intentions, among which the "Create new class" as in the picture below:
[image]

There are a few [extra things](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html) you get only in the ultimate edition, but the java intentions do not seem to fit in this category.

Comment: @Morific Sorry, forgot to mention it was for Scala. For Java it works as expected.